# Prometheus filtering based on Labels - error

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql

we were using this query to to expect the **pod/namespace** for the cpu metrics and use the **kube_pod_labels** to get the pod name based on labels.

```
max(kube_pod_labels{label_workflow_instance_id="$workflow_instance_id", label_workflow_vertex_id=~"$workflow_vertex_id", pod=~".+"}  * on(pod) group_left sum by(pod) (label_replace(node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_irate{namespace="pipeline-worker", container_name!="POD"},"pod", "$1", "pod_name", "(.+)")) * on(pod) group_left kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running"}) by(label_workflow_vertex_id)
```

able to see empty query result for this. we are having out cluster over EKS(attached the grafana UI screenshot)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KCwn.png)

Any help here would be highly associated ( like what i am doing wrong here )

Answer (score 1):

adding these to args in kube-state-metric deployment in k8s
- --telemetry-port=8081
- --metric-labels-allowlist=pods=[*]
will help you.

[image]

#-------------------------------------

```
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - --port=8080
    - --telemetry-port=8081
    - --metric-labels-allowlist=pods=[*]
    - --resources=certificatesigningrequests,configmaps,cronjobs,daemonsets,deployments,endpoints,horizontalpodautoscalers,ingresses,jobs,leases,limitranges,mutatingwebhookconfigurations,namespaces,networkpolicies,nodes,persistentvolumeclaims,persistentvolumes,poddisruptionbudgets,pods,replicasets,replicationcontrollers,resourcequotas,secrets,services,statefulsets,storageclasses,validatingwebhookconfigurations,volumeattachments
    image: registry.k8s.io/kube-state-metrics/kube-state-metrics:v2.9.2
```

Answer (score 0):

At [www.asserts.ai](http://www.asserts.ai) we record the container CPU Metric with the following record rule

It looks like you are using the kube_mixin  so recording rules for `mixin_pod_workload` is probably already there in your environment

```
sum by (pod, container, namespace, node, job, workload, asserts_env, asserts_site) (
            rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total {container != "POD", image != "", container != ""}[5m])
            * on (pod, namespace, asserts_env, asserts_site) group_left(workload)
            mixin_pod_workload
            * on (pod, namespace, asserts_env, asserts_site) group_left()
            group by (pod, namespace, asserts_env, asserts_site) (kube_pod_labels)
          )
```

Comment: Am i doing this wrong ? btw we are on kSM version 2.2.0 and i feel the kube_pod_labels prom metric doesn’t have the pod labels. 
i was going through this and tried to add the attribute - --metric-labels-allowlist=pods=[*] but this seems to be not working too for me. 
Any suggestion here ?